# How to get an iframe to load in in the front of my page on top of the existing page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am trying to have a link to an iframe load a frame on top of my page. Is there a javascript way to do this?

I have this in my code but I want that link to load within my page on top of a google map...

```
<div>
    <iframe src="/static/flaggingCriteria.html" name="flaggingCriteria" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: I don't have any :) -- what do I need to do to the CSS to get that link to load in front?

Comment: In your CSS you would need to set the z-index for the div that the iframe is in to something high, so it appears over any other content. I would suggest z-index: 1000;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say load a frame on top of your page, do you mean a modal window ?

If that is the case Fancy box will let you do that very easily it will let you load iframe into a modal window.  http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<div style="z-index:1000;position:absolute;">
    <iframe src="/static/flaggingCriteria.html" name="flaggingCriteria" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
</div>
```